# Magento: Which is optimized way to get single record?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, model, getmodel

**load by Id**

```
$data = Mage::getModel('module_name/model)->load($id);
```

**or**

```
//collection by filter

$data = Mage::getModel('module_name/model)->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id',$id);
```

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. The question already has been asked, so I answered it in the duplicate linked above. *TL;DR:* It depends what you need because both give **different results**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper method to get single record : `Mage::getModel('module_name/model)->load($id);`

If you use getCollection() then it will load all the record of that particular table and then it will filter the record from all collection.

While load() will fetch only single record from that table.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. Is there any way to calculate load time of both queries in magento?

Comment: Calling a collection does NOT load each item. Each record will be contained within the collection but `->load() ` is not called on each object and as such the object is not actually loaded. However, you are correct that loading a single record by ID is the most efficient way.

Comment: @Vishal you can use xdebug's profiler to determine memory and time calculations.

Comment: You can use this extension to get all query time detail.
https://www.mgt-commerce.com/magento-developer-toolbar.html